# sublime text 3 - 3114 have error

Tags: 15.10, sublime-text

Sublime text recently release new package sublime-text_build-3114_amd64 but It showing error while I am trying to install it. Here it's screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gotta do a purge first, then install you .deb

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer
sudo dpkg -i sublime-text_build-3114_amd64.deb
```

Comment: let me check @IDSFN